# If I am open same fragment twice mean app will be closed

Tags: android, android-fragments

If i try to open same fragment twice means app will be closed. 
kindly provide any idea
My code is :

```
if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

       fragment1.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact_us) {

        ragment2.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback) {

        fragment3.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment3).commit();
    }
```

Comment: In first `else if` block it should be `fragment2` instead of `ragment2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add tags to yours fragments and test if the current fragment hase same tag.

```
if (id == R.id.nav_home && getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment1")==null) {

   fragment1.setArguments(arguments);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1,"fragment1").commit();

}
```

Comment: Thanks Samir. I got a anwser

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response